# What does Ptolemy mean by "a line drawn from the centre of the earth through the centre of the moon to a point on the ecliptic"

Tags: the-moon, coordinate, ecliptic

This is from a translation of Ptolemy's *Almagest*:

> Hence it necessarily follows that the straight line drawn from the
> centre of the earth (which is the centre of the ecliptic) through the
> centre of the moon- to a point on the ecliptic, which determines the
> true position ([as it does] for all bodies).

I don't understand what is means when is refers to "a line drawn from the centre of the earth through the centre of the moon to a point on the ecliptic. If the moon is on the ecliptic why must this line go through it. If it is not on the ecliptic how can a straight line go through its centre to a point on the ecliptic?

Comment: We may need more context, but my interpretation is drawing 2 lines: one from the Earth to the Moon, and one from the Moon to the ecliptic. Essentially, forming a plane that is probably perpendicular to the ecliptic. This gives the ecliptic longitude, and the height of the Moon off the ecliptic gives the ecliptic latitude.

Comment: The Almagest doesn't describe a current model of the solar system. You may get better answers at the "history of science" stack exchange.

Answer (score 4):

In his model, Ptolemy considered the ecliptic to be the path of the Sun—hence, a distinct circle than the path of the Moon. In modern terms, one could say that Ptolemy thus (rightly) considered the *orbit* of the Moon as distinct from the ecliptic.

If I’m not mistaken, your quote is from the beginning of Book IV of the *Almagest*. Further in the same Book, in Chapter 5, Ptolemy draws a diagram where “the circle concentric with the ecliptic be ABG on center D and diameter AD, and let the epicycle [of the Moon] be EZ on center G.” [Toomer’s translation, p. 181, with diagram on p. 188.] The diagram makes it clear that the ecliptic is *not* considered to be the projection of the Moon’s monthly path in the sky.

I have translated the *Almagest* to French and present it statically in a PDF at https://ecliptiqc.ca/Almageste.pdf ; there is also an interactive version of this very diagram at https://ecliptiqc.ca/Almageste_Livre4.php#IV5 (scroll a little down). While it’s all in French, it’s rather easy to understand even if you don’t read French, and there are free translation tools online.